# How to create callable array of functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

I want to create an array which can be extended at any time by any of my functions and also can be called (all functions in that array shall be called on array call). How to do such thing with javascript and jquery?

Why I need such thing:

I created 1 big and 25 small JS files each of the small files can be or not included into document. Each small file generates some html when it wants to. But when it generates new html I often need some kind of UI refreshment - some divs to be resized or at least size checked etc. So I need an array of functions for all small JS scripts to put into it all UI refreshment they need, on the onter hend each small JS file will call that array when it creates some more HTML code. (If there was somjething like $(document).htmlDataChange in jQuery I would not need such thing at all.)

Comment: It would be useful if we knew why you wanted this. Your use case might be better served by a different approach than an array of functions.  In Javascript, you can hook up multiple event handlers for a single function.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Could you show us some pseudocode or something? Do you want an array of functions, or do you want to extend the array object by adding your own functions to its prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an object that has a property to hold the functions, and add, remove, and run methods.

```
var myobj = myobj || {};
    myobj.functions = [];
    myobj.add = function(fn){
                  myobj.functions.push(fn);
                };
    myobj.remove = function(fn){
                     myobj.functions.splice(myobj.functions.indexOf(fn), 1);
                   };
    myobj.run = function(){
                  myobj.functions.forEach(function(cb){ 
                    if (typeof cb == "function") {
                      cb.call(); 
                    }
                  });
                };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always extend Array using its prototype.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function (param) 
{
    // Do Stuff
};
```

Example how to clear an array

```
Array.prototype.clear = function()
{
    this.length = 0;
};
```

jQuery also has
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

you can't use array for this since thet don't have a key property:

```
//create the object
var myObj = {};
//you fill it as you like
myObj.see = function(param){//do something}
myObj.hear = function(param){//do something else}
myObj.feel = function(param){//do something else again}

//once you are ready, you can call the functions as shown below:
myObj.see();
myObj.hear();
```